# Как совершить действие (например удалить файл) при завершении сессии PHP

Tags: php, файлы, сессия

Например пользователь авторизовался, в результате его действий на сайте был создан файл. Нужно, чтобы после закрытия им страницы или выхода (то есть при удалении сессии) созданный файл был удален с сервера. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавте ваш код.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: Насколько критично не удалять файл сразу, а спустя какое-то время? Может, тут имеет смысл не привязываться к сессии? Или же хранить данные из этого файла прямо в сессии, т.к. когда она удалится - вместе с ней и все связанные данные.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно вызвать функцию session_set_save_handler() и установить обработчик destroy/gc. Когда PHP будет убивать сессию, он вызовет Ваш обработчик и в нем Вы почистите каталог.
Пример использования функции session_set_save_handler() :

```
<?php
function open ($save_path, $session_name) {
global $sess_save_path, $sess_session_name;

$sess_save_path = $save_path;
$sess_session_name = $session_name;
return(true);
}

function close() {
return(true);
}

function read ($id) {
global $sess_save_path, $sess_session_name;

$sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
if ($fp = @fopen($sess_file, "r")) {
$sess_data = fread($fp, filesize($sess_file));
return($sess_data);
} else {
return(""); // Здесь обязана возвращать "".
}

}

function write ($id, $sess_data) {
global $sess_save_path, $sess_session_name;

$sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
if ($fp = @fopen($sess_file, "w")) {
return(fwrite($fp, $sess_data));
} else {
return(false);
}

}

function destroy ($id) {
global $sess_save_path, $sess_session_name;

$sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
return(@unlink($sess_file));
}

/*******************************************************************
 * Вам понадобится реализовать здесь какой-нибудь *
 * вариант утилиты уборки мусора.*
 *******************************************************************/
function gc ($maxlifetime) {
return true;
}

session_set_save_handler ("open", "close", "read", "write", "destroy", "gc");

session_start();

// продолжить нормальное использование сессий

?>
```

По идее, если код в папке изменяется, то дата изменения файлов тоже, то есть сессия активная. Можно удалять папку, если файлы с кодом в ней долгое время не изменялись.

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали о существовании этой функции, но честно говоря я не смог разобраться как конкрето она действует и как привязать к ней скрипт удаления файла.

Answer (score 0):

Простого и надежного способа фиксации момента закрытия браузера нет.
Выход пользователя - когда он посещает специальную страницу и выполняется код очистки сессии PHP - да такое есть. 
Расскажите поподробнее про задачу.

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо всем. 
Я решил задачу способом, который подсказал Ruslan Yarullin.
При отрытии страницы я запускаю php скрипт из другого айла (KillPDF.php). В файле открытой страницы этот скрипт запускать нельзя, так как из за функции  sleep() браузер постоянно грузиться, что может не понравиться пользователю. 
Функцией ignore_user_abort(true) делаю так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся и после разрыва соединения с пользователем, устанавливаю таймер на 15 минут функцией sleep(900), после чего файл должен быть удален. Если же пользователь остается на странице более 15 минут и ему нужен доступ к файлу, то я через JS перегружаю страницу и файл создается заново.

```
    if($_GET["file"]) {
    $filename = $_GET["file"];
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    sleep(900);
    unlink($filename);
    }
```